# Как можно реализовать данный дизайн Android приложения?

Tags: android, ui, design, android-menu

Есть карточка "2" для добавления пользователя и **Action bar** "1".
Вопрос в том, как мне лучше реализовать это?

Я знаю, как добавлять кнопки в **Action bar** посредством **Menu**, но каким образом их можно разместить так, как на картинке, т.е. **крестик** слева, а **Add** справа? Я так понимаю, что для этого необходим стиль для Action bar?

По поводу карточки "2", я так понимаю, что её в данной ситуации лучше всего реализовать через фрагмент, т.к. мне необходимо динамически изменять пункты меню, но возникает вопрос, каким образом мне можно добавлять разделители "3", как на рисунке, т.е. вертикальные и горизонтальные разделители, но не способом добавление обычного **View** шириной в 1dp, а атрибутом, и каким образом можно убрать разделитель у **EditText** не используя изменение заднего фона на прозрачный? Есть ли специальный атрибут для этого?

Также хотелось бы узнать по поводу затенения контура вокруг карточки "2". Как вы считаете, его нужно сделать через новомодный Elevation или просто задать параметр shadow?

Самый же главный для меня вопрос, как добавить пункты меню так, как это изображено на рисунке, остальное и сам могу заколхозить, но хотелось бы сделать это так, как надо это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Упс, забыл добавить картинк, сейчас поправлю

Comment: 1 - кастомный экшнбар, 2 - тень и закругленные углы у контейнера (CardView), 3.1 - кастомный разделитель в списке,  3.2 - вертикальные разделители? В этом или в чем проблема? Распишите поподробнее в вопросе

Comment: Вы думаете, что тут необходимо использовать Card View?

Comment: Нет, не необходимо, но можно попробовать. В крайнем случае - 9patch. Здесь несколько вопросов, лучше разделить на несколько тем

Comment: Хорошо, тогда подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать подобное через Card View, просто я сам никогда не использовал данный View, он работает на подобие Layout-ов? могу ли я наполнять его элементами на подобие Layout-ов?

Comment: По поводу моего же комментария выше, я разобрался с Card View и да, их можно и, как я понял, нужно наполнять на подобие Layout-ов, тем самым мы просто создаём всё, как обычный Layout, и делаем обёртку в Card View

Comment: CardView - это FrameLayout с  возможностью закруглить углы и добавить тень. Не знаю, получится ли она точно такой же, как на скриншоте, но будет что-то подобное.

Comment: Насчет кнопки-крестика: после `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`  добавьте  `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`  `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`  `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`  `actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.cross);` и обрабатывайте методом `onOptionsItemSelected` по id `android.R.id.home`

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, по поводу коммента выше, тоже спасибо, я уже и сам нашёл способ, просто вспомнил, что когда-то уже делал такое и просто порылся в старом коде

Comment: Если вы знаете знаете ответ к своему вопросу, стоит опубликовать его здесь для того, чтобы люди, столкнувшиеся с подобной проблемой, могли его найти. Более того, ответы на собственные вопросы приветствуются на so.

Comment: Тут несколько вопросов в одном. Пожалуйста, разделяйте вопросы. Так на них сложно отвечать, да и искать неудобно.

Comment: [CardView наследуется от ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) — это значит, что он может содержать детей. И, хотя это наверное неправильно, сам наследник `CardView` может позиционировать их (детей).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для создания ACtionbar, необходимо было использовать кастомный Actionbar ([пример](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)), Для создания Карточки "2", необходимо было использовать [Card View](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), для добавления разделителей ничего лучше не придумалось, как создать свою [View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128764/3789850) шириной в 1 dp, задать ему нужный (серый) цвет и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо action bar используй toolbar он намного функциональный и позволяет без труда добавлять элементы на подобие добавления элемента в layout.

[Toolbar](http://androiddocs.ru/toolbar-alternativa-actionbar/)

Comment: Спорит не буду, Toolbar в данный момент куда лучше, чем Action bar, и лучше было бы использовать его, тем более Toolbar новая возможность сосульки и грех её не пользоваться, но в данной ситуации не требовалось каких-то сложных извращений, поэтому можно было обойтись и Actionbar